# How to fix "T does not conform to bound <: AnyKind"?

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types, zio, type-kinds, zio-http

I have the following ZIO project

```
object MinimalCounterexample extends ZIOAppDefault {

  val fetch = {
    for {
      result <- Client.request("http://localhost:9123/whatever")
      data   <- result.body.asString
      _      <- zio.Console.printLine(data)
    } yield ()
  }

  override def run = fetch.provide(
    EventLoopGroup.auto(),
    ChannelFactory.auto,
  )

}
```

When I compile this I get this error:

```
io.netty.channel.ChannelFactory[io.netty.channel.Channel] does not conform to bound <: AnyKind
```

What gives? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is due to passing `-Yno-kind-polymorphism` to the scala compiler.

Removing this flag from `scalacOptions` in `build.sbt` fixes the problem.